# C# - Obter ConnectionString do AppSettings.Json de uma aplicação dotNet Core MVC a partir de uma Library de acesso a dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, connectionstring, configurationmanager

Possuo uma aplicação em .Net Core MVC e nela faço a parte de acesso a dados utilizando uma Dll. 
Como configuro uma Connection String de acordo com o que foi configurado no meu appSettings.Json da aplicação NetCore MVC?

```
    private static string _ConnectionString;

    private static string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return _ConnectionString; }

        set
        {
            _ConnectionString = 
                "Data Source=SERVIDOR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID; Password=Password; Initial Catalog=BASE";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tornando a _ConnectionString pública e atribuindo o valor na startup?

Answer (score 2):

Olá, usando uma webapi aspnet core voce pode fazer da seguinte forma. Veja se pra voce isso resolve, ou se pode adaptar para seu problema

No `controller` você cria um construtor que receba uma `IConfiguration` e atribua para uma variavel privada, posteriormente vc pode utiliza-la invocando da seguinte forma `configuration["ConnectionString"]` vide o exemplo

### O appsettings.json

```js
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionString": "Host= localhost; user= user; pass=pass"
}
```

### O Controller

```cs
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private IConfiguration configuration;
    public ValuesController(IConfiguration config){
        configuration = config;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get()
    {
        return Ok(configuration["ConnectionString"]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Olá, é possível você utilizar a connectionString, com o método : Configuration.GetConnectionString("nome da variavel no appSettings")